# Node.js - pass variable between sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Say I have this code in node.js:

```
app.post('/stuff', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
app.route('*').all(function(req,res,next){
  res.write('Hello World');
});
```

There are 2 routes here - one is a catch-all for any request to the server and the other is what to do if a post request with a route of /stuff is sent.

Is it possible to pass a value local to the post request into route?

Intended Program flow: initial request to the server goes through route (which has controls not illustrated to ignore post requests) and the connection is left open, then a post request is sent from the initial request and is dealt with by app.post - can a value found within the closure of post be passed to the initial request that is still open?

I am trying to avoid using Global variables, and res.local only has a local scope. Also trying to keep clean so if I can use native express or node.js all the better. Much obliged for any help.

Comment: See express [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session).  After creating the session, you just put a variable into the session that you can then access on subsequent requests from that client.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, will have a look, was trying not to include any modules too...

Comment: Well, you are asking for session-like functionality (something that preserves state across requests).  You can either make your own or just include a module that has already written it for you or I supposed you could set a cookie with a value, but you will want a module for handling cookies too.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is true that session like behaviour is what I am looking for. I am still new to node and not too clear on how it handles multiple requests from the same origin, also while the connection is still open.

Comment: A session sets a cookie that identifies a particular client and then stores a data structure locally in the server for each client.  An incoming connection can be matched with its session data by the value of the session cookie.  I linked you an express session module in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

> then a post request is sent from the initial request

Why don't you simply pull out the POST function and call it from both handlers, that way you don't need to send a seperate request from inside your app.

```
var postHandler = function(req, res) {
   res.send('hello world');

   // Just return whatever you want back to the calling function
   return someValue; 
};

// Set it as the handler for post.
app.post('/stuff', postHandler); 

app.route('*').all(function(req,res,next){

  // Call function.
  var returnValue = postHandler(req, res);
  res.write('Hello World');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how postHandler will fire subsequent to the initial request and pass a value into the initial request...the data needs to travel from app.post into the initial app.route

Answer (score 0):

```
app.route('*').all(function(req,res,next){
  if (req.originalUrl === '/stuff') {
    req.variable = 'some value';
    return next();
  };
  res.write('Hello World');
});


app.post('/stuff', function(req, res){
  var value = req.variable;
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

You can try this code. Please take the order of `app.all` and `app.post`.

The second way, your can try `app.locals` http://www.expressjs.com.cn/4x/api.html#app.locals

> The app.locals object is a JavaScript object, and its properties are
>   local variables within the application.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go - thought I had tried something similar and that req.variable in post would only be local to the new request for a post, not the previous initial request which has nothing to do with the subsequent post (and indeed provides code for the post to execute).

Comment: @user1360809 Do you try `app.locals`?

Comment: app.locals is a global variable to the app, I wanted to keep it all specific to the request so it closes down easily.